# Cleanup Logical Replication slot Postgres

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a logical slot in my Postgres (version 13). My consumer was down for some time and the slot size shot up to 100GB. I don't care about the logs generated during the downtime. Basically the wal in 100GB are not useful to me. How I can cleanup the slot to like 0KB.

I **don't** want to drop the slot though.

As per the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-admin.html).

> Returns changes in the slot slot_name, starting from the point from which changes have been consumed last. If upto_lsn and upto_nchanges are NULL, logical decoding will continue until end of WAL.

this should do the job

```
SELECT pg_logical_slot_get_changes('slot_name'::text, NULL, null);
```

. Is it true ?

Also is there any faster way to the same.

Comment: `select pg_replication_slot_advance('slot_name', pg_current_wal_flush_lsn());` would probably be more appropriate to skip all changes.